# Print permissions from file arguments in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having trouble reading the permissions of file arguments. I looks like it has something to do with hidden files but I'm not sure why.

Current Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage ./checkPerm filename [filename2 ... filenameN]"
    exit 0
fi

for file in $@
do
    ls -l | grep $file | cut -f1 -d' '

    # Do Something

done
```

I can get the permissions for each input, but when a hidden file is run through through the loop it re-prints the permissions of all files.

```
-bash-4.1$ ll test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user joe 0 Nov 11 19:07 test1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 user joe 0 Nov 11 19:07 test2*
-r--r----- 1 user joe 0 Nov 11 19:07 test3
-rwxr-x--- 1 user joe 0 Nov 11 19:07 test4*
-bash-4.1$ ./checkPerm test*
-rw-r--r--
-rw-r--r--
-r-xr-xr-x
-r--r-----
-rwxr-x---
-r--r-----
-rw-r--r--
-r-xr-xr-x
-r--r-----
-rwxr-x---
-bash-4.1$
```

What is going on in the loop?

Comment: What hidden file are you talking about?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. Then it will show each line as it's executing it, so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Why are you using `ls -l | grep $file` instead of `ls -l "$file"`?

Comment: @Barmar `grep` has always confused me. `ls -l "$file"` fixed the problem.

Comment: Is the second file named `test2` or `test2*`? What is your `ll` alias?

Comment: FYI, hidden files have names beginning with `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your grep:

```
ls -l | grep 'test2*'
```

This will grep out anything starting with `test` since you're basically asking for anything starting with `test` that might end with 0 or more `2`s in it, as specified by the `2*`.

To get your intended result, simply remove your loop and replace it with this:

```
ls -l "$@" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Or keep your loop, but remove the grep:

```
ls -l $file | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Also, technically, none of those files are hidden. Hidden files in bash start with `.`, like `.bashrc`.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Thought it was the * the meant hidden for some reason... I just knew it was those files that caused the problem.

Comment: `*` isn't part of the filename. `ls` puts `*` after the filename when the file is executable.

Comment: @Barmar maybe in other shells, yes, but not in bash4+ with default `ls -l`.

Comment: @MannyD `ls` isn't part of the shell, it's a program. It's actually the `-F` option that makes it add these markers; I assume that's what the OP's `ll` alias does.

Comment: @Barmar I doubt it. In his script, he uses `ls -l` and there'd be no way he'd be getting this erroneous output if it just iterated `test1 test2 test3 test4`.

Comment: So it's just a coincidence that the executable files have `*` after them, which is exactly what `ls -lF test*` would show?

Comment: Possibly, really depends on his alias of `ll` like you said, but I was able to reproduce his exact case with the asterisks in the filename. Also, take a look at his output: see how the first two lines are the same? That's obviously test1 appearing twice. First when doing `ls -l | grep test1` and the second time when doing `ls -l | grep test2*`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the `ls -l` inside the loop and then `grep` the results, if there are files that contain `test1` in the name, but not at the start, they are selected by the `grep`, giving you extra results.  You could see that by doing:

```
ls -l | grep test
```

and seeing that there are many more entries than the 4 you get with `ls -l test*`.

Inside your loop, you should probably use just:

```
ls -ld "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1
```